# Expression eager in Frege but lazy in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, frege

In Haskell, the following code prints "[1,2,3,4,5":

```
foo = take 10 $ show $ numbersFrom 1 where 
  numbersFrom start = start : numbersFrom (start + 1) -- could use [1..]
```

But in Frege, It throws `OutOfMemoryError` with the following code:

```
foo = take 10 $ unpacked $ show $ numbersFrom 1 where
  numbersFrom start = start : numbersFrom (start + 1)
```

Here the only difference is the `unpacked` function which is necessary to convert from `String` to `[Char]` and FWIW, the `unpacked` function is eager. Why can't the whole expression be lazy as in Haskell? Is it possible to achieve something similar to Haskell in Frege here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I haven’t used Frege, but it seems to me that if `unpacked` is strict, then its argument ought not be an infinite list. Try `unpacked $ take 10` instead of `take 10 $ unpacked`.

Comment: Strings in Frege are not lists. So `take 10` cannot be applied to the result of `show`. Hence `unpacked` is used to first convert from `String` to `[Char]` and then `take 10` is applied on the list.

Comment: So what are `String`s in Frege?  It appears they are `java.lang.String` (see the Frege Language definition).  You will never get around to evaluating `unpack` as it will never be able to build the string!

Answer (score 7):

I don't know Frege, but according to the language definition `String` is `java.lang.String` so you can't build infinitely long strings (the out of memory issue probably has nothing to do with `unpack` being eager).

Because you know each element of `numbersFrom 1` will be shown as at least 1 character then you can over-approximate the size of the list to show then unpack, then take the number of desired characters:

```
foo = take 10 $ unpacked $ show $ take 10 $ numbersFrom 1 where
  numbersFrom start = start : numbersFrom (start + 1)
```

Or more generally:

```
n = 10 -- number of characters to show
m = 1  -- minimum (map (length . show) xs) for some type of xs
foo :: a -> [Char]
foo = take n . unpack . show . take ((n+m-1) `div` m) . someEnumeration
  where
  someEnumeration :: a -> [a]
  someEnumeration = undefined
```

If your enumeration is expensive then you can start taking into account the number of commas, whitespace, etc and reduce the argument to the second `take`, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 4):

This will not work because of the infinite string that is (not) being produced by `show`.
You would need some helper function that converts a list to a list of `Char`.

It would probably be good to have a standard function for this.

---

Edit Feb 22th 2013

Class `Show` has now a new method:

```
{--
    'showChars' addresses the problem of 'show'ing infinite values.
    Because 'show' has type 'String' and 'String' is atomic, this would
    try to create a string with infinite length, and hence is doomed to fail.

    The default definition is

    > showChars = String.toList . show

    This is ok for all finite values. But instances for recursive types
    should implement it in a way that produces a lazy list of characters.

    Here is an example for the list instance:

    > showChars [] = ['[', ']']
    > showChars xs = '[' : ( tail [ c | x <- xs, c <- ',' : showChars x ] ++ [']'] )

-}
showChars :: show -> [Char]
showChars = String.toList . show
```

The Haskell code that led to the `OutOfMemoryError` can now be written as:

```
(println . packed . take 10 . showChars ) [1..]
```

Answer (score 4):

Adding to other answers,

Since `show` returns a `java.lang.String`, it is not possible to show infinite lists. So I thought I could write a different version of show to return a `[Char]` instead. This is what I have come up with and it is working.

```
frege> :paste
class AltShow a where
  altshow :: a -> [Char]

instance AltShow AltShow a => [a] where
  altshow [] = []
  altshow xs = concat $ (['['] : intersperse [','] ys) ++ [[']']] where
    ys = map altshow xs

instance AltShow Int where
  altshow = unpacked <~ show

intersperse :: a -> [a] -> [a]
intersperse _ [] = []
intersperse _ (x:[]) = [x]
intersperse sep (x : y : []) = 
  x : sep : y : []
intersperse sep (x : y : rest) = 
  x : sep : y : sep : intersperse sep rest
:q
Interpreting...

frege> altshow [1, 10, 2, 234]
res3 = ['[', '1', ',', '1', '0', ',', '2', ',', '2', '3', '4', ']']
frege> :t res3
res5 :: [Char]
frege> packed res3
res6 = [1,10,2,234]
frege> :t res6
res7 :: String
```

Now the code in the question becomes similar to Haskell and it is not exploding with OutOfMemoryError:

```
frege> :paste
foo = take 10 $ altshow $ numbersFrom 1 where
  numbersFrom start = start : numbersFrom (start + 1)
:q
Interpreting...

frege> foo
res9 = ['[', '1', ',', '2', ',', '3', ',', '4', ',', '5']
frege> packed foo
res11 = [1,2,3,4,5
```

Comment: I think we could add a class operation to `Show` that does it this way and whose default implementation is `toList <~ show`

Comment: Yes, that is a better way. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: Strings are strict in Frege, but lazy in Haskell.

*Lists* are lazy in both languages. But in Frege, Strings are not lists.